# React event listener not working in production on Netlify

Tags: reactjs, dom-events, netlify

I have a calculator react app.
I added an event listener on the document to listen for keyboard inputs.
I used a useEffect hook to set the listener and remove it on unmount.

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keyup', keyboardInputHandler);
    return document.removeEventListener('keyup', keyboardInputHandler);
  }, [])
```

However, the listener works on my localhost, but not in the version deployed on Netlify. No errors, nothing. Simply ignores keyboard inputs.

[Live demo deployed on Netlify](https://slaven-calculator.netlify.app/)

[My Github repo](https://github.com/BSlaven/my_calculator)

I asked the same question on Github and Netlify forums.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It's strange behavior.

However, you should have a clean-up function inside the `useEffect`.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keyup", keyboardInputHandler);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("keyup", keyboardInputHandler);}, []);
```

Comment: Not what is causing my problem.